# How to form regex to match everything up to a "("

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how can a regular expression be formed to match everything up to and NOT including an opening parenthesis "("?

example input:

`"12(pm):00"`
`"12(am):))"`
`"8(am):00"`

ive found `/^(.*?)\(/` to be successful with the "up to" part, but the match returned includes the "("

In regex101.com, its says the first capturing group is what im looking for, is there a way to return only the captured group?

Comment: I think this should work - `/^([^(]+)/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to deal with this. The first is to restrict the characters you match to not include the parenthesis:

```js
let match = "12(pm):00".match(/[^(]*/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

The second is to only get the part of the match you are interested in, using capture groups:

```js
let match = "12(pm):00".match(/(.*?)\(/);
console.log(match[1]);
```

The third is to use lookahead to explicitly exclude the parenthesis from the match:

```js
let match = "12(pm):00".match(/.*?(?=\()/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

As in OP, note the non-greedy modifier in the second and third case: it is necessary to restrict the quantifier in case there is another open parenthesis further inside the string. This is not necessary in the first place, since the quantifier is explicitly forbidden to gobble up the parenthesis.

Comment: why does testing this in the chrome console result in undefined?

Comment: Because `console.log` returns `undefined`, after having printed out what it needs to print out?

Comment: im confused...if I copy and paste your suggestion into chrome console and execute, it returns only `undefined`, just trying to test this

Comment: My Chrome console prints out `12`, then prints out `undefined` under that, for each of the three cases. You can have it _only_ print out `"12"` by using `match[0]` instead of `console.log(match[0]);` If your Chrome does anything differently, I have no clue what's going on. Unless you're just copy-pasting the first line, which should display only `undefined`, as all `let` statements do.

Comment: ahh yes for some reason trying to log it, would result in only `undefined`. +1

Comment: #4, find the index of the first left parentheses using method that employs a regex or not. If there is such an index, `idx` (i.e., if there is at least one left parenthesis), extract the first `idx` characters from the string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I restricted to only regexp-only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^\d+
```

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

https://regex101.com/r/C9XNT4/1